# Mute Shortcut Ctrl+Shift+M does not longer work in Microsoft Teams

Tags: 20.04, shortcut-keys, microsoft-teams

I am using Microsoft Teams 1.4.00.13653 on Ubuntu 20.04 with the standard desktop.

Several months ago, I was able to Mute/Unmute during a Call using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> (teams window focused). Some other shortcuts (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> to open the Teams-calendar seem to work)

This is not working anymore since a while. I am note sure if it is due to a teams update or another change to the system.

- Is anybody else experiencing this issue?
- How can this be debugged / fixed?

EDIT: For other colleagues it seems to work. I am wondering if the shortcut is bound by some other software. I already checked the shortcut settings of Gnome, and there is no <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> in use. Is there any command to list all the currently assigned shortcuts of the system?

EDIT2: I am able to assign <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to something else (for testing purpose) using gnome keybindings, so I believe this is not bound to another application yet.

Comment: What does this mean? In earlier times, I was able to Mute/Unmute during a Call What is in earlier times? Has there been a teams update and now it does not work? Question needs some details.

Comment: Actually I wrote it in the next paragraph ... it stopped working at some point in time, hard to say when, but it's absolutely possible it's due to a Teams update.

Comment: I have same problem on Red Hat 7 with Teams 1.4.00.26453.

Comment: I have the same problem on ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

Try using the "other" <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>. I find it does not work with the left side <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, but does work with right side <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.